# Accessing Shared Outlook Subfolders With Python

Tags: python, outlook

I have a script that goes through and moves emails in personal subfolders to various network locations and archives the emails to keep my inbox clean.

I want to deploy this to the team as we have a shared email account, yet I can't access the shared folders in this shared account.

For Example, my folders in outlook are diagrammed below:

```
1. me@company.com
     - Inbox
          -Sub Folder 1
          -Sub Folder 2
2. sharedAccount
     - Inbox
          -Sub Folder 1
```

I can connect to my sub-folders just fine and the inbox for the shared account, but I can't get to the shared sub folder 1.

Any suggestions? I'm using Python 3.7 and Win32, code is shown below:

```
import win32com.client
    from datetime import datetime
    import time
    print('Archiving Emails')
    print('')
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNameSpace('MAPI')
    inbox = outlook.Folders('shared')
    inbox = inbox.Folders('Inbox')
    test = outlook.Folders('shared').Folders('Inbox').Folders.Item('sub folder 1')
```

This works fine and lets me access the emails when I point it to my account, but fails at the test line when I point it to the shared email

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Gets inside the Folder for the Shared Mailbox:

```
     folder = outlook.Folders.Item("NameofYourSharedFolder")
```

To access the Inbox of the Shared Mailbox:

```
     inbox = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(6)
```

To access another Folder within the Shared Mailbox:

```
     archiveFolder = folder.Folders.Item("MyArchive")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: Thank you @Marina Aguilar! The Item attribute seems to be missing in the 7th line of the Code. Moreover for accessing Shared Mailbox, in Outlook, it needs to be specified else it will access the Default Inbox set up with the User's account.